# Simulink - Zero Order Hold transfer function

Tags: control-system, matlab, simulink

I am trying to discretize the transfer function of my compensation.

After modelling my system in continuous domain thanks to books of Christophe Basso and books of Erickson Robert W., Maksimovic Dragan, I did the compensation of my system in the continuous domain but by knowing that I will discretize this compensation. So I needed to take into account the effect of sampling and of the ZOH in the continous domain for doing the right compensation (as some of the members of this forum help me to do it). Then I used the "tustin" method for discretizing the transfer function of my compensation.

In order to be sure of my results, I decided to use Simulink to verify that the 2 systems, the one in the continuous domain and the one mixed between continous and discrete, give the same response. Here is my problem they do not give the same response.

Here is the transfer function of my compensator in the discret and continuous domain for a phase margin equal to 70°

[image]

Here are what I wanted to simulate on Simulink.

The first picture is in the continuous domain with the Zero Order Hold block given by Matlab where we can set the "sample time" to the value we want. I set it to 200 µs as my sampling frequency is 5kHz

[image]

The second picture is in the continuous domain with the transfer function of a Zero Order Hold find on wikipedia with "T" set to 200µs :

[image]

[image]

And when I look the response between the both circuit where only the ZOH block is different, the responses of the different diagramm are differents. This is a point that I do not understand. And I would say that the correct simulation is the one with the transfer function of the ZOH from wikipedia as regards of the response and the effect of the phase margin on the response.

The third picture is the mixed diagramm :
[image]

Finally here are the responses :

[image]

where the green response whose the settling time and rise are the longest corresponds to the 1st picture and the third picture. They completely fit, so it is not possible to see 2 curves. And the blue reponse corresponds to the 2nd picture (the one with the ZOH transfer function from wikipedia which according to me seems to be the right... )

[image]

According to me all the diagramms that I showed you are the same, or actually I set it to be the same ... Could you, please, tell my why the systems are different ?

Tell me if you need more informations.

Thank you very much and have a nice day :)

----------------------------------E D I T-----------------------------------

The *parameter control box* is an *LTI Block* and its parameter is the transfer function *sys_zoh" whose the definition is the following :

[image]

I added the ZOH block :

[image]

I am sorry for the late response, I do not have matlab at home ...

---------------------- DOUBLE EDIT ----------------------------------------

Here is how I define the *sys_zoh* transfer function and its bode plot

[image]

[image]

Thank you :)

Comment: I can't fully understand what your doing, but if you have discrete controller and a continuous plant, the usual approach is to combine \$(1-e^{-sT}) \rightarrow \frac{z-1}{z}\$ with the controller, and \$\frac{1}{sT}\$ with the plant. Then z-transform the continuous bits (or use the bilinear transform), and finally combine everything into a ZTF.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! @Chu I do not do what you are saying :/ I just place a transfer function into the S domain. $$\dfrac{1-e^{-sT}}{sT}$$

Comment: @AJN I will modify the post for updating the informations :)

Comment: @Chu I will try to do what you say :) If you have any book to recommand me, do not hesitate :)

Comment: @Chu I can not do what you are saying in your first comment. I have a mixed system. The compensation of the system is done numerically the rest of the system is done analogicaly. Nevertheless for studying the stability of my system, I do not know how to do it with a mixed system. So in order to obtain the discrete transfer function of my compensation, I decided to represent my whole system in the S domain and by taking into account the effect of sampling and DAC in the S domain. Then I could design a compensator correctly in the S domain that I would simply discretize it to obtain adiscrete TF

Comment: So If I want to be in the S domain i cannot introduce discrete transfer function as you suggest to do for taking into account the ZOH

Comment: @AJN I edited the post for updating it and answers to your questions :)

Comment: I will show you ! It is just based on the workspace variables. it allows you to used the variables of a code without changing the name value in simulink of the different LTI blocks. There is a video on this subject. I will try to find you because I am not sure to be clear ... https://fr.mathworks.com/videos/transfer-functions-in-simulink-part-1-creating-and-using-transfer-functions-106146.html

Comment: @AJN It seems to be wrong but how can the bode plot to be correct ? In the sense of Y is not equal to 0

Comment: In any case, I try to replace it with the 1st order pade approximation and it does not resolve the problem ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127437/discussion-between-jess-and-ajn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it was my bad. Everything is working perfectly on Matlab. The error was coming from the definition of the ZOH transfer function. I added a gain G0 as you can see. And this gain was not take into account on the other diagramms, so it could not fit with the diagramm with the LTI system block *sys_zoh*... Here are the results between the mixed system and the continuous system. As you can see the ZOH and sampling effect seems to be correctly took into account.

[image]